# Iframe history navigate not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, history

I'm working on a micro-frontends project where the sub-apps are loaded in iframes.
When trying to use history back in the iframe, is not working at all with the latest version of Chrome. Tried it on Firefox also and it behaves correctly.

Do you know anything about this issue? Maybe a workaround?

Many thanks